# (Re)rendering Backbone view in change event handler does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-stickit

I'm having two form elements, both 2-way-databinded via backbone.stickit.
The second form element (*#input*) is just cosmetics - there for showing it's actually working.

The idea is that my View gets (re)rendered,every time the option inside the dropdown (*#select*) menu gets changed.

I'm trying to achieve that by catching the the 'changed' event of #select and call this.render() to (re)render the view.

Apparently that doesn't work. The selected option doesn't get saved back into the model and I fail to understand why.

I'm not looking for a *solution*, rather than an *explanation*, why the following code doesn't work. The solution (as in: works for me) is part of the fiddle - commented out.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl">
  <h1>Hello <%= select %></h1>
  <select id="select">
  </select>
  <p>Select:
    <%= select %>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <p>Input:
    <%= input %>
  </p>
</script>

<div id="ctr"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    select: "",
    input: "",
  }
});
FooView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#ctr',
  template: _.template($('#tpl').html()),
  initialize() {
    this.model.bind('change', function() {
      console.log("model change:");
      console.log(this.model.get('select'));
      console.log(this.model.get('input'));
    }, this);
    //this.model.bind('change:select', function() { this.render(); }, this); // <--------------------- WORKS
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.stickit();
    return this;
  },
  events: {
    'change #select': function(ev) {
      console.log('change event triggered:');
      console.log(this.model.get('select'));
      console.log(this.model.get('input'));
      this.render(); // <--------------------- DOES NOT WORK - WHY?
    },
    /* 'click #render': function(ev) {
      console.log('render event triggered:');
      console.log(this.model.get('select'));
      console.log(this.model.get('input'));
      this.render();
    } */
  },
  bindings: {
    '#input': 'input',
    '#select': {
      observe: 'select',
      selectOptions: {
        collection: function() {
          return [{
            value: '1',
            label: 'Foo'
          }, {
            value: '2',
            label: 'Bar'
          }, {
            value: '3',
            label: 'Blub'
          }]
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
new FooView({
  model: new Foo()
}).render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r7vL9u07/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work to call `this.render()` from within your `change #select` event handler is because you are disrupting the two-way data binding that [Backbone.stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/) is providing you. The flow goes something like the following:

- User changes the value of '#select'.
- Your `change #select` handler fires and calls `this.render()`.
- `render` repopulates `#ctr` with a new select menu with no selected `option`.
- Backbone.stickit responds to the change to `#select`.
- Backbone.stickit tries to obtain the value of `#select`, but since it contains no selected `option` the value is `undefined`.
- Backbone.sticket sets the `model`'s `select` attribute to `undefined`.

The reason it works if you move the `this.render()` call to within the `model`'s `change:select` handler is because Backbone.stickit is able to correctly update the model without the DOM changing before it gets the chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. Doing so via model.bind('change:select') is the proper way to do it then?

Comment: If you want to re-render when the select is changed, then yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!